# Custom popover for iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller

In the iBooks application, the brightness, font and search views subclass UIPopOverController but without border.
Is there any way to mimic those views?

Comment: Did you ever find how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The border may be from using a UINavigationController for the popup.  I'd try using a plain UIViewController instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover the arrow + bg are images, I guess we can replace that with transparent bg.

It can be used with iPhone as well.